# What should I do with duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicates

I recently noticed a handful of [late answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers?pagesize=15&filter=week) trickle through that more or less mimic a previous answer. Should these be flagged or downvoted or both?

Comment: These all seem to be by first time posters. They do seem a bit 'me too' or too much like others, but since they just started here they can't really post them as comments (where they seem more appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

If they are low rep users that can't post them as comments (rep less than 50), @RegDwight has said that we should flag them so that he can move them to comments.

Otherwise, I'd say comment to suggest that they make it a comment if it's not an answer, downvote it if it's an answer but not a good answer, and flag it if it's a duplicate of another answer.

Comment: I hadn't seen this question before, but it somewhat overlaps with [one I've just posted](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/where-to-draw-the-line-in-plagiarism-of-earlier-answers). What would you expect the moderator to do if the later answer was almost entirely a duplicate, but perhaps slightly better phrased, referenced, or just adding some minor (but 'desirable') extra point?